# angular form validation error shows [null]

Tags: angularjs

I can't find out where is the error in my form.
I have a select of two items and an input for each of them.
When I choose one of the items my form `myform.$error` shows `{"myform":[null]}` when I input some variable it show `{}` - my form is good.
I can't find what does this expression mean: `{"myform":[null]}`

Comment: Any code sample would be appreciate :)

Comment: Please post a HTML snippet and JS file demonstrating the problem.

However, have you put the ng-form directive with your form name at the top of the HTML file?